# What variable does projectile-recentf use to store recent files?

Tags: projectile

I have trouble with projectile-recentf, in that it seems to forget files I've worked with.

What variable does it use to hold the recent files?

Answer (score 1):

Projectile retrieves files by filtering the files from the `recentf-list` variable. Emacs 'keeps track' of recent files if recentf-mode has been activated (i.e. add `(recentf-mode)` to your init file).

Between Emacs sessions, Emacs stores the files in the `recentf-save-file`.